# transfering large files using UDP in java

Tags: java, udp

How do I transfer large files more than 64kb from client to server Using `UDP` in java? (I want to transfer `audio/video` files)
I know `TCP` is better than `UDP`, but this is my assignment to transfer file through `UDP`.Can anyone show me some codes for above problem statement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at open-source projects which have done this before, such as [Java-UDP-File-Transfer-Made-Reliable](https://github.com/Michaelcj10/Java-UDP-File-Transfer-Made-Reliable); however, these libraries try to mimic TCP transfer reliability. If you have both UDP and TCP as a choice, you'd better to go with TCP.